# How to get ram and cpu info using AmazonEC2Client in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

In my Asp.Net Core 3.1 project I am using AmazonEC2Client for getting info about AWS instances.
I implemented helper method for getting instance list.Method looks like:

```
         public static async Task<List<string>> AwsList(string awsAccessKeyId, string 
         awsSecretAccessKey)
        {
            AmazonEC2Client client = new AmazonEC2Client(awsAccessKeyId,awsSecretAccessKey, 
            RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
            bool done = false;
            var instanceIds = new List<string>();
            DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
            while (!done)
            {
                DescribeInstancesResponse response = await 
                client.DescribeInstancesAsync(request);
                foreach ( Reservation reservation in response.Reservations)
                {
                    foreach (Instance instance in reservation.Instances)
                    {
                        instanceIds.Add(instance.InstanceType);
                    }
                }

                request.NextToken= response.NextToken;

                if (response.NextToken == null)
                {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            return instanceIds;
        }
```

Json result is:

```
[
    "t3a.xlarge",
    "t2.medium",
    "t2.medium",
    "t2.micro",
    "t3a.xlarge",
    "t2.medium",
    "t3a.xlarge",
    "t3a.xlarge",
    "t3a.xlarge"
]
```

I dont know ram and cpu info inside instance type or not, no experience with aws.
I would like to get cpu and ram info according to instance type.
Later I would like to create method which is accepting **string instanceType** and according to this get ram and cpu.
For ex: GetRam("t2.micro") -> 2gb

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I woul like to implement code which is getting ram from aws and show as result,unfortunately there is no example for c# in documentation

Comment: [`Instance`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TInstance.html) class has `CpuOptions` property. You can also associate the memory size and cpu count with instance type using document above

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski for cpu it worked but I am not able to find ram, it has ramdiskid which is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **DescribeInstanceRequests** need to be use **DescribeInstanceTypesRequest** and appropriate response as well.

```
foreach ( var instanceType in response.InstanceTypes.Where(x => x.InstanceType  == name))
{
       instanceIds.Add(instanceType.MemoryInfo.SizeInMiB); // ram
       instanceIds.Add(instanceType.VCpuInfo.DefaultVCpus); //cpu
}
```